# Using CSS to place a symbol linked to a text phrase into a document's margin

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin, css-position

I'm looking for a way in CSS to place a symbol into the margin of the document to highlight/indicate the position of some special phrase in the text body of the document. Think of the usual text-editors in programming IDEs that place little warning icons in the margin next to lines that contain errors.

This is easy to do if the document consists of non-wrapped single lines. Then I can just check if the line needs the symbol and place it manually.

But it gets tricky if I want to, for example, place an icon for spelling mistakes in a document where the browser automatically breaks the lines. Then I would have to have a way to figure out which line the spelling mistake ended up in. This is probably also possible with JS by checking the y-coordinate of some wrapper-span that marks the spelling mistake, but I'm looking for something more elegant.

Is there some trick with float-left or absolute positioning that allows me to, for example, put this marker symbol into the span that marks the error and have it be placed in the left margin of the document instead of inside the boundaries of the span?

Comment: And what kind of mark-up are you using?

Comment: @DavidThomas Not sure I understand your question... I'm using `!doctype  html`. I'm not really too worried about whether I enclose the text-block to mark in a span or u or b tag. It probably doesn't make much difference in terms of the CSS either, right?

Comment: What I'm asking is what HTML are you using to enclose the text that requires icons to be placed in the margin? What you ask might be easy, but without any idea of what you're working with this question is *way* to broad, and cannot be reasonably answered (since we have to guess what you're doing, and what you've got so far).

Comment: @DavidThomas Christian provided the perfect answer I was looking for. Maybe from there it's clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the answer is *exactly* as you described. Have spans wrapping your text, and inside the span, include an icon element. Then float it left, and set a negative margin on it. Example:

CSS:

```
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Markup:

```
<span class="selected"><span class="icon"></span>this is some text in a span. </span>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FQCsn/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I guess I should have just tried it. I somehow assumed that the float left would float the icon inside the span element rather than the enclosing div...

Comment: Can I add a bonus-question? Is it possible to add a hover-effect to the text when I hover over the icon? :)

Comment: You could apply a hover state to the `.selected` span, but this would also take effect when you hover the text by itself. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FQCsn/1/). Unfortunately there is no such thing as a parent selector in CSS. But you could use jQuery instead, like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/FQCsn/8/). Sure, it's not as semantic, but what's more important - semantics or your user's experience?

Comment: I found a way to do it with a sibling-selector: http://jsfiddle.net/FQCsn/16/ Thank you for your help! This is working really well!

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't even think just to wrap the text in another span. Nice work. Stack Overflow needs more users like you.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's also an application for the `position: absolute` in the context of the `:before` pseudoelement. Try this and see if it gives you what you're looking for:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
<style>
.allowLeftMargin
    {
        margin-left: 5em;
    }
.highlightThis
    {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
.highlightThis:before
    {
        background-color: yellow;
        content: "Note";
        padding-left: 0.25em;
        padding-right: 0.25em;
        position: absolute;
        left: 1em;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="allowLeftMargin">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    <span class="highlightThis">Excepteur sint occaecat</span>
    cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can quickly adjust the size of the browser window to confirm that the note moves with the highlighted span.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put a strong around the spelling error, add another tag (a span for example) right after that spelling error, and set that span in position: absolute, but without the "top" property (because the top position is variable). Put that span in width: 100% in order to "select" the line, and add another tag inside that span (a i tag for convenience), and use it to put your icon.

```
p{ line-height:20px; margin:20px;}
strong{ color:red;}
span{ display:block; height:20px; left:0; position:absolute; width:100%;}
i{ background:red; display:block; height:12px; left:0; position:absolute;
top:-16px; width:12px;}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fwZqv/1/

Try to change the width of the "Result" window and see how it behaves.

It's not a perfect solution, and I would rather use JS for that matter.